# OpenVPN still opening login page after uninstalling it

Tags: uninstall, openvpn

I installed OpenVPN from .deb package. Now I have uninstalled it with

```
dpkg --purge openvpn
```

and also tried

```
apt purge openvpn
```

but when I visit my server address via browser it still opens the OpenVPN login page and I can't access any other folders on my server e.g. serverip/example

Comment: OpenVPN doesn't *have* a login page that comes with its package.  AnyConnect-like things do, but not OpenVPN.  If you are getting a login page for OpenVPN when you are attempting to access your server via Web Browser, then start by clearing your internet cache before pointing fingers at OpenVPN.  If you are *still* getting such a login page, then your remote server may be misconfigured.

Comment: Tried clearing internet cache, not working. I use apache but don't know how to fix this since I didn't do any manual config. If some part of OpenVPN wasn't left I'm sure I wouldn't be getting this. Tried using find command to find OpenVPN leftovers but nothing. Here is my server: http://klincic.com.